# How to sign apk programmatically with "apksig library" in Android studio

Tags: android, apk-signing

Some days ago, I learned java then jumped to Android studio :) and I am working on an app, as feature of this project, `select and sign other apk` and out signed apk, I saw some good libraries like `"apksig"` also jarsigner source, but unfortunately there is no any example how to do this process in android studio, I spent 3 days in searching and digging in source code,The difficulty lies in how to pass the parameters like `"x509 cert"` and `"private key"` in the required form and some other stuffs. maybe I can get help by simply example to sign demo apk by this library or any other way. Thanks

Comment: Can you [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70043592/edit) to clarify what you mean by `I need to sign apk programmatically from code` as Android Studio already uses [gradle to sign the APK](https://developer.android.com/studio/run#changing-variant) or are you trying to [sign from the command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline)

Comment: Hi, sorry to make confused words, what did I mean, In my project  I need to sign other apk and generate signed apk, not from command, but from project itself programmatically via "com.android.apksig" library, but I didn't find example about using this library. In other words in my app "select apk from input and sign it" this need code example, maybe can help. Thanks again